# Mounting 40 iSCSI HP 3PAR SAN volumes in single CentOS7 server

Tags: nginx, centos, storage-area-network, iscsi, centos7

I need to mount 40 HP 3PAR SAN volumes iSCSI LUN/target in single CentOS7 server that run nginx, each volume size is 8 TB, and that 40 mount points need to appear as single share path.

Does such configuration have big impact on performance? In other words, what is the recommended method (performance wise) to access 320TB as single share path?

additional info:
The storage (320 TB) contains HLS VOD contents.
Number of users will access HLS streams only 30 users, this is why I think single Nginx instance should be sufficient.
CentOS7 filesystem I am using is XFS.

Comment: What does 'single share path' mean here?  You want to present all these luns to a file server which shares them out as one share?  If so, make a parent folder, then mount the luns under that folder in child folders.  Share out the parent folder.  Simple and effective.  Not sure on performance, but I have 12 LUNS of various sizes totaling 180TB mounted in a nested fashion which are then shared out of three shares and accessed by 25 people.  Performance was fine.  RHEL7 for the file server, EMC for the SAN storage array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does such configuration have big impact on performance?

Depends on the filesystem used and how they extents/LUNs are bound - you could easily have a situation where one extent/LUN 'fills up' before it moves onto the next one - meaning you'd not 'smear' out writes across them all. I'll be honest I don't know how XFS does this, worth looking at.

Either way it doesn't seem like a particularly stupid thing to do, I'd personally be tempted to present a LUN of that size from a NAS such as a NetApp rather than via block but I imagine the 3Par will be in place already?

Comment: Since its VOD the only other consideration is if it makes sense to have that many LUNs, but I suspect that's already in place.

Comment: HP 3PAR, already purchased, I tried to make the question scope limited, the full project contain many other parts yet its not related, VOD contents will be written on each volume in rolling buffer fashion (similar to DVR), so i am not sure if 'smear' point about writing applied in my case, otherwise please explain to me further because I might misunderstood.

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh Interesting that it's VoD - I've been a VOD-specific designer/engineer for a decade now so this is really my thing. I also wish I only had 30 users to worry about instead of millions - that would be so nice. Anyway I'd still be very careful about creating a single filesystem this way, if you can please try to mount each LUN as a separate filesystem I'd be a lot happier.

Comment: its great to have an input from an expert like you, so you advice to keep each 8 TB LUN mounted independent, that's mean nginx will have 40 mount points instead of one (initially i wanted nginx to access the whole 320 TB from single root path) , i am fine with your recommendation. what about NFS? do I need NFS if i followed your suggestion?

Comment: I do something similar and I use NFS 100% rather than LUNS, specifically from a NetApp filer cluster - be aware that HPE now offer NAS services on top of 3Par kit, you could look into that?

Comment: are you trying to say, that NAS services gives better performance over block? if i misunderstood, please explain further, also the SAN have multi I/O, not sure if that's related.

Comment: storage product is: HPE 3PAR 8440 4N

Comment: I couldn't find reference to NAS services for 3PAR! can you point me out to a link? and I hope you update your answer to include what's being discussed in comments and explaining ' I use NFS 100% rather than LUNS' , to mark it as an answer.

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh not performance no, more about overall system stability/fragility - certainly binding lots of LUNs into one XFS FS will work but it makes me nervous - if you lost a single LUN you lose the whole FS - I've been doing IT system design for over 25 years now (very old :) ) and always try to build the most robust system that will do the job, yeah I care about performance but I need something to work every minute of every day if possible and the idea of binding all those LUNs bothers me and personally I like and trust big resilient NAS's for such things.

Comment: oh and http://www8.hp.com/uk/en/products/data-storage/3parfileservices.html